# Allocate console with library macOS C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there's a way to allocate a console to a library when it is injected into a process?

This library would be injected with [osxinj](https://github.com/scen/osxinj).

When I say allocate, I mean create one and be able to output and input text.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this was inject the library/dylib into a console application.